# How to show text with ellipses inside a table having an anchor using only css

Tags: html, css

How to show text with ellipses inside a table having an anchor tag using only css without using table-layout: fixed;

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> 
      <a href="">
          very lengthy text
      </a> 
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

use css class like-->

> ```
> .truncate {
> width: 250px;
> white-space: nowrap;
> overflow: hidden;
> text-overflow: ellipsis;
> }
> ```

Comment: Where i have to put this class? i have put this class for td, but it is not working only.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this :-

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/hU9Y2/1/

```
.ellipse{
    border:solid 1px #000;
    border-radius:30px;
    padding:0px 5px;
}
.ellipse2{
    border:solid 1px #000;
    border-radius:50%;
    padding:10px 5px;
}
```

Comment: I need the ... at the end of the lengthy text. not ellipse background.

Comment: i did't use ellipse as a  backgorund,you mean ellipsis http://curiousdesign.ie/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Ellipsis.jpg?

Comment: Yes i need ... at the end

Comment: please check the below answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900512/how-to-show-text-with-ellipses-inside-a-table-having-an-anchor-using-only-css/21901217#21901217 :)

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/hU9Y2/2/

.ellipsis {

```
border-bottom: dotted 1px #000;
width: 7px;
margin-left: 2px;
height: 14px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution in the fiddle

[Fiddle-ellipse](http://jsfiddle.net/vinishanto/Xcyh4/)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> 
        <div class = "elipse">
      <a href="">
          very lengthy text
      </a> 
        </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

css

```
.elipse{
    background-color : aqua;
    border-radius : 50%;
    padding : 20px;
}
```

Comment: I need the ... at the end of the lengthy text. not ellipse background.

Comment: you mean dotted lines around the text or an ellipse after the text

Comment: for example if i have a text "what is your name?" then it show show like "What is your ..." once the width of the text crosses some fixed width

Comment: if you need to hide you can try like this http://jsfiddle.net/vinishanto/hU9Y2/3/ but you need to use JavaScript for displaying ... only when the text is long and hide when it's short .